# Update field in salesforce - php sforce

Tags: salesforce-id, php, php-toolkit

I am trying to update a field in salesforce and for some reason it doesn't do anything.
here is my code:

```php
class Salesforce {

    private static $mySforceConnection;

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {
        self::$mySforceConnection = new \SforceEnterpriseClient();
        self::$mySforceConnection->createConnection(storage_path("app/wsdl/wsdl.xml"));
        self::$mySforceConnection->login();
    }
 
    static public function updateOppertunityStatus($status,$recordId){

        $records = new \stdClass();
        $records->ID = $recordId;
        $records->Status__c = $status;
        self::$mySforceConnection->update($records,'Opportunity');
    }

}
```

I can connect to salesforce and retrieve data and for some reason, the update does not give me an error but not updating the field. also checked that the ID is correct.

Thanks

Comment: After calling `update` what does the response look like from the Salesforce server? Is it an HTTP 200?

Comment: for some reason I am getting this error:
"message: "Id not specified in an update call"
what should I do?

Comment: The error is actually really helpful in this case. It's letting you know at least one of the `$records` passed to `update` is missing an `Id`. I am not familiar with the PHP library you're using but I would double-check that `$recordId` is not `null` in `updateOppertunityStatus` and that `$records->ID` is valid syntax. Check that `ID` isn't causing issues on the SOAP API side and that the API isn't expecting lowercase `id` or `Id`.

Comment: I tried all the combined cases for id (ID,Id,id) none of them work. i pass correct values for the recordId also checked

Comment: Hi, 
for some reason it said that the id is null but this is the object I pass:
```
Status__c: "Completed (Full)"
fields: null
id: "0065A00001bIdfPQAS"
type: "Opportunity"
```

Answer (score 1):

ok.
I solved the issue. it seems that were two mistakes the id suppose to be written Id and the object suppose to be in an array:

```
  static public function updateOppertunityStatus($status,$recordId){

        $records = new \stdClass();
        $records->Id = $recordId;
        $records->Status__c = $status;
        $update = self::$mySforceConnection->update(array($records),'Opportunity');
        return $update;
    }
```